# Autocomplete not detecting the correct value from object properties Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-reactive-forms

I've a huge list of `counties` and want to implement an auto complete feature.
I'm using the same form to `add` a new customer or `update` an existing customer.

Now, the problem is that for adding a new customer, my program works perfectly, but when I updates it, in county dropdown list it show the `countyId` instead of `name`.
How do achieve that ?
see the images in order

county schema is as

```
{
  countyId: number;
  name:string
}
```

I'm trying with the following code in html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-4">
    <mat-label>County</mat-label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="County" name="" matInput formControlName="countyId" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let county of filteredCounties | async" [value]="county.name">
            {{county.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in my component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerService } from '../../../../services/customer/customer.service';
import { CountyService } from '../../../../services/county/county.service';
import { SubCountyService } from '../../../../services/subCounty/sub-county.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import PNotify from 'pnotify/dist/es/PNotify';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-customer',
  templateUrl: './new-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-customer.component.scss']
})

export class NewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSending = false;
  customerId;
  updatePerson;
  updatedCustomer;
  ready = false;
  dialogView;
  ref: ComponentRef<any>;
  newCustomerForm: FormGroup;
  counties; // list of counties
  subCounties;
  filteredCounties: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private countyService: CountyService,
    private subCountyService: SubCountyService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewCustomerComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public display: any
  ) {
    this.dialogView = display.view;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.customerId = params.get('customerId');
      if (this.customerId) {
        this.customerService.getCustomer(this.customerId).subscribe((response) => {
          this.updatePerson = response;
          this.newCustomerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            name: [this.updatePerson.name, Validators.required],
            nationalId: [this.updatePerson.nationalId, Validators.required],
            gender: [this.updatePerson.gender, Validators.required],
            phone1: [this.updatePerson.phone1],
            phone2: [this.updatePerson.phone2],
            bishopName: [this.updatePerson.bishopName, Validators.required],
            bishopPhone: [this.updatePerson.bishopPhone, Validators.required],
            countyId: [this.updatePerson.countyId, Validators.required],
            county: [this.updatePerson.county, Validators.required],
            subCountyId: [this.updatePerson.subCountyId, Validators.required],
            address: [this.updatePerson.address, Validators.required],
            additionalInfo: [this.updatePerson.additionalInfo],
            input1: [this.updatePerson.input1],
            input2: [this.updatePerson.input2],
            defaultingRecord: [''],
          });
          this.ready = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        this.ready = true;
        this.newCustomerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          nationalId: ['', Validators.required],
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          gender: ['', Validators.required],
          phone1: [''],
          phone2: [''],
          county: [''],
          countyId: ['', Validators.required],
          subCountyId: ['', Validators.required],
          bishopName: ['', Validators.required],
          bishopPhone: ['', Validators.required],
          address: ['', Validators.required],
          additionalInfo: [''],
          input1: [''],
          input2: [''],
          defaultingRecord: [''],
        });
      }
    });
  }

  // tslint:disable:typedef
  ngOnInit() {
    // Getting the list of counties
    this.countyService.getCounties().subscribe((response) => {
      this.counties = response;
      this.newCustomerForm.patchValue({
        county: response
      });
      if (!this.customerId) {

        this.filteredCounties = this.newCustomerForm.get('county').valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
          map(value => this._filter(value))
        );
      }
    }, error => {
      this.counties = [
        {
          "countyId": 63,
          "name": "Mombasa"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 64,
          "name": "Isiolo"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 65,
          "name": "Murang'a"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 66,
          "name": "Laikipia"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 67,
          "name": "Siaya"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 68,
          "name": "Kwale"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 69,
          "name": "Meru"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 70,
          "name": "Kiambu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 71,
          "name": "Nakuru"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 72,
          "name": "Kisumu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 73,
          "name": "Kilifi"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 74,
          "name": "Tharaka-Nithi"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 75,
          "name": "Turkana"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 76,
          "name": "Narok"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 77,
          "name": "Homa Bay"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 78,
          "name": "Tana River"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 79,
          "name": "Embu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 80,
          "name": "West Pokot"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 81,
          "name": "Kajiado"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 82,
          "name": "Migori"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 83,
          "name": "Lamu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 84,
          "name": "Kitui"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 85,
          "name": "Samburu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 86,
          "name": "Kericho"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 87,
          "name": "Kisii"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 88,
          "name": "Taita-Taveta"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 89,
          "name": "Machakos"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 90,
          "name": "Trans Nzoia"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 91,
          "name": "Bomet"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 92,
          "name": "Nyamira"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 93,
          "name": "Garissa"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 94,
          "name": "Makueni"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 95,
          "name": "Uasin Gishu"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 96,
          "name": "Kakamega"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 97,
          "name": "Nairobi"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 98,
          "name": "Wajir"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 99,
          "name": "Nyandarua"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 100,
          "name": "Elgeyo-Marakwet"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 101,
          "name": "Vihiga"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 102,
          "name": "Mandera"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 103,
          "name": "Nyeri"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 104,
          "name": "Nandi"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 105,
          "name": "Bungoma"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 106,
          "name": "Marsabit"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 107,
          "name": "Kirinyaga"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 108,
          "name": "Baringo"
        },
        {
          "countyId": 109,
          "name": "Busia"
        }
      ];
    });
    // Getting a list of sub-counties
    this.subCountyService.getSubCounties().subscribe((response) => {
      this.subCounties = response;
    });
  }
  displayFn(county?: any): string | undefined {
    return county ? county.name : undefined
  }
  private _filter(value) {
    console.log('value: ', value);
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.counties.filter(county => county.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
  addCustomer(customer) {
    console.log('Value of customer form before setting is: ', this.newCustomerForm.value);
    const selectedCountyId = this.counties.filter(county => county.name === this.newCustomerForm.value.countyId)[0];
    console.log('CountyId: ', selectedCountyId);
    if (!selectedCountyId) {
      PNotify.error({
        title: 'Please selecte a valid county',
        minHeight: '75px'
      });
      return;
    }
    this.newCustomerForm.patchValue({
      countyId: selectedCountyId.countyId
    });
    customer.countyId = selectedCountyId.countyId;
    console.log('Value of customer form after setting is: ', this.newCustomerForm.value);
    this.dataSending = true;
    this.customerService.addCustomer(customer).subscribe((response) => {
      if (this.dialogView) {
        PNotify.success({
          title: 'Customer added Successfully',
          minHeight: '75px'
        });
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
      else {
        PNotify.success({
          title: 'Customer added Successfully',
          text: 'Redirecting to list page',
          minHeight: '75px'
        });
        this.dataSending = false;
        document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = 'initial';
        this.router.navigate(['searchcustomer']);
      }

    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Following error occured: ', error);
      PNotify.error({
        title: 'Error occured while adding customer',
        text: 'Failed to add new customer',
        minHeight: '75px'
      });
      this.dataSending = false;
    });
  }

  updateCustomer(customer) {
    this.dataSending = true;
    this.updatedCustomer = this._formBuilder.group({
      customerId: [this.customerId],
      nationalId: [customer.nationalId],
      name: [customer.name],
      gender: [customer.gender],
      phone1: [customer.phone1],
      phone2: [customer.phone2],
      countyId: [customer.countyId],
      subCountyId: [customer.subCountyId],
      address: [customer.address],
      additionalInfo: [customer.additionalInfo],
      bishopName: [customer.bishopName],
      bishopPhone: [customer.bishopPhone],
      input1: [customer.input1],
      input2: [customer.input2],
    });

    this.customerService.updateCustomer(this.updatedCustomer.value, this.customerId).subscribe((response) => {
      PNotify.success({
        title: 'Customer updated Successfully',
        text: 'Redirecting to list page',
        minHeight: '75px'
      });
      this.dataSending = false;
      this.router.navigate(['searchcustomer']);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('An error occured while updating customer: ', error);
      PNotify.error({
        title: 'Error occured while updating customer',
        text: 'Failed to update customer',
        minHeight: '75px'
      });
      this.dataSending = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Pictures for better understanding
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feed the autocomplete an id, that is what it will show. In your first image where you say it works, it looks like it works, but in fact it is not storing the `countyId` when a choice is made, but the `name` property which you have set as `value`. I would assume that it is actually the id you want stored there too.

The cleanest solution in my opinion, is to actually store the whole county object. So I would suggest the following:

```html
<input type="text" matInput formControlName="county" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let county of filteredCounties | async" [value]="county">
    {{county.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

with that I removed the `countyId` formcontrol and instead added `county`, which stores the whole object and added `displayWith` to show the `name` property of the county.

Then modify the `valueChanges` to check if user has typed or it has been fed an object:

```ts
// add the correct name of your form
this.filteredCounties = this.myForm
  .get("county")
  .valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(""),
    map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
    map(value => this._filter(value))
  );
```

and the `displayFn` which is shown in template:

```ts
// don't use 'any' !!
displayFn(county?: any): string | undefined {
  return county ? county.name : undefined
}
```

So now is only left the option where you want to create the edit form. If you only have the `countyId` property, you can use `find` to add the correct object. Here in this sample I set it on creation, but you will maybe use `setValue()`, but the idea is the same!

```ts
// replace 2 with the variable/prop you have the desired id
county: [this.counties.find(x => x.countyId === 2)],
```

So now you have the whole object. When submitting form and if you only want the `countyId` from the form control, you can access it by: `this.myForm.get('county').value.countyId`.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxnicq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html)** **with the above code.**

Comment: I'm able to type in input field, but the data is not being filtered, I think that the reason is because  I don't have the list of counties in my `form`, rather I'm getting them from a separate service and populating in html and my `form` 
I've posted the complete code of my component, please have a look

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the issue is exactly? Why isn't it filtering? You mentioned nothing of that in your question? Could you please fork my stackblitz and show the issue. You can mock your http-request `getCounties()` with using rxjs `of`, like this: `of(an array of counties here)`.

Comment: I mean, whatever I type in input, it doesn't filter the list, all of the items in dropdown stays the same,
I'm unable to create a stackblitz because it require http request requires authentication and token or else it doesn't returns the data

Comment: as I said, you can mock your http-request with rxjs using `of(an array of  counties here)`.

Comment: Alright, I'm replicating my component, but a slight help is needed here, as I'm unable to import `of` from `rxjs`
How do I include `rxjs` extension in my project ?
I googled but couldn't find any solution, because I'm using a material project

Comment: Not even I'm able to import in your `stackBlitz` link

Comment: no need to import it. **fork** it, add code to showcase the issue and share the link :)

Comment: Just import `import { of } from 'rxjs'`;´

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206374/discussion-between-lint-and-ajt82).

Comment: Thanks you much for a very detailed answer, atlast I was able to figure out where I was wrong.
Thanks once again